# Get last matched value after backslash in Hive

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, special-characters, hiveql

I want to extract the last part of the path. For eg if my path is:

```
\\abc.ksiw.com\POP-K-DRIVE\project-app\cname\554789A
```

I want `554789A` as output.

I tried with `regexp_extract(col, '[\\w+]+$',0)`  but that does not work. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
regexp_extract(col,'([^\\\\]*)$',1)
```

Backslash is special character both in Hive and in regex.

Four back slashes is used to represent a single backslash in regex.

If you want to test on literal constant, use two backslashes instead of one in literal and four in regexp:

```
select regexp_extract('\\\\abc.ksiw.com\\POP-K-DRIVE\\project-app\\cname\\554789A','([^\\\\]*)$',1);
```

Result:

```
554789A
```

`(\\w+)$` also works:

```
regexp_extract(col,'(\\w+)$',1)
```